# iOS: access company internal webapp from native Safari

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, citrix

We have an existing internal web app called `http://sexywebapp`

The goal is to enable seamless remote access on employee devices to SexyWebApp. 
Currently we target native Safari on iOS 8.1+/Android 4.4+.

While we've been able to use Citrix Receiver to get folks using SexyWebApp via Chrome/IE on top of XenApps, it's really clunky. Forcing desktop browsers onto iPhones just isn't going to fly.

Ideally there's a way we could go into iPhone's native Safari and navigate to `http://sexywebapp` just like we can when physically in the office.

It seems like if we set up a standard VPN this might be possible - any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's certainly possible. If you're looking for a Citrix way of doing this then look at XenMobile and the Worx suite of apps. Citrix WorxWeb is a native browser for your iOS and Android devices. However it uses a micro-VPN to connect into your data-center, allowing you to access internal company web sites.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what we've built up and so far so good.
To others coming from a web dev background, heads up there's lots of complexity on this path but it does get you there. 
Expect to learn app wrapping and cert management and other corporate firewall inanity. You'll likely want a consultant.